# How to call one custom helper function in another custom helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to use one helper function in another helper function. In below code I want to highlight last name if it contains "Finch" word. I have writtern helper class for that. 
If we use in hbs file then syntax would be {{highlight name}}.
But how to use it since I have to use it in another helper class.

Below is my code:

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(person) {
    return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
  });

   Handlebars.registerHelper('highlight', function(person) {    
var item = (person.lastName).replace('Finch', '<span style="color: red">' 
  + Finch + '</span>');
return new Handlebars.SafeString(item); 
  });
```

Here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wC6JT/4/

Here is the fiddle where "highlight" helper is called.: http://jsfiddle.net/wC6JT/3/ . This will not produce any results since we will get console errors for person.lastName not recognized in "highlight" register helper.

I want to use "highlight" helper in fullname helper  for person.lastName.
How can this be acheived.

Comment: @muistooshort : I have updated my code and fiddle. Its typo. it is person.lastName

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract the contents of the method you want to use in the first method into its own javascript method. Then call that javascript method in both helpers as necessary.

You can't do it unless you refactor the contents of one of the methods into its own javascript method.

So in your case it should look something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(person) {
    return person.firstName + " " + highlightJavascript(person);
  });

Handlebars.registerHelper('highlight', highlightJavascript);

highlightJavascript : function(person) {
   var item = (person.lastName).replace('Finch', '<span style="color: red">' 
  + Finch + '</span>');
return new Handlebars.SafeString(item); 
}
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle: it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/wC6JT/14/ . If I remove highlight helper then it works but its displaying whole <span> tag instead of html thing.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong with fiddle but I have implemented in my application and its working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `Handlebars.registerHelper('highlight', highlightJavascript(person));` be `Handlebars.registerHelper('highlight', highlightJavascript);`? You want to give `registerHelper` the function, not call it.

Comment: @CorayThan any method other than above answer, actually i need to call   helpers based on arg comes in parent helper..

Comment: @Arjun T Raj Sorry, that goes a bit beyond my Javascript expertise.

Answer (score 7):

To call a Handlebars helper from another function, you can use [`Handlebars.helpers`](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/3a9440f954092558275cd4c05a35ba34bcbfa210/lib/handlebars/base.js#L39):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(person) {
    var lastName = Handlebars.helpers.highlight.apply(this, [person.lastName]);
    var firstName = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(person.firstName);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(firstName + " " + lastName);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('highlight', function(str) {    
    var safeStr = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(str);
    var item = safeStr.replace("Finch", "<em>Finch</em>");
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(item); 
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acLcsL6h/1/

Read [this blog post](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2013/04/07/handlebars-helper/) for another example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this way: http://goo.gl/oY4IIO
need not concatenate string.

```
<script id="tmp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>test:   {{test   "2.3333333"}}</p> 
    <p>format: {{format "2.3333333"}}</p>
</script>
```

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('format', function (value) {
   return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
});
Handlebars.registerHelper('test', function (value) {
    var source = '{{format x}}';
    var context = {x:value};
    var html = Handlebars.compile(source)(context);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(html);
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    var source = $('#tmp').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template();

    $('#main').html(html);
});
```

output:
test:   2.33
format: 2.33

Comment: You should include the main content from link here as if link changes your answer would be invalid.

Comment: @user3250923: Hmm Nice one. But after a long Time. Thanks for the link. Please include the link content.